# How can I pass a super-class object to a sub-class constructor?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clos

Let's say I have class `A` with a couple of slots:

```
(defclass a ()
  ((a-1 :initarg :a-1)
   (a-2 :initarg :a-2)))
```

And class `B` that inherits from `A`:

```
(defclass b (a)
  ((b-1 :initarg :b-1)))
```

If I want to instantiate `B`, `make-instance` will offer me slots `:a-1`, `:a-2` and `:b-1`.

Here is a crazy idea: what if I want to instantiate `B` using the existing instance of `A` and only filling slot `b-1`?

PS. Why it can be useful: if `A` implements some generic methods that `B` inherits directly, without adding anything new. In alternative approach, making instance of `A` to be a slot in `B`, I would need to write trivial method wrappers to invoke these methods on that slot.

The only way I can think of: in auxiliary constructor decompose object `A` and pass corresponding slots to `make-instance` for `B`, i.e.:

```
(defun make-b (b-1 a-obj)
  (with-slots (a-1 a-2) a-obj
    (make-instance 'b :b-1 b-1 :a-1 a-1 :a-2 a-2)))
```

Are there better ways of doing this? (or perhaps, this approach leads to very bad design and I should avoid it altogether?)

Comment: You can also take an instance of A and change its class to B - then initializing the added slots. Note that you really need to get rid of the 'A implements methods' thinking. This is CLOS, where classes/slots and generic functions/methods are a bit more independent.

Comment: @RainerJoswig It's interesting idea of changing the class. But I'm not sure if I fully understand you on relation between classes/slots and generic functions/methods. I realize they are quite independent entities. What would be an alternative to 'A implements method' thinking?

Comment: @mobiuseng in clos, it's not that "a implements method f",is that "there's a method defined on the generic function f specialized for a". It's a more noticeable difference when you're specializing methods on multiple arguments.

Comment: Joshua is right. Plus: "there ARE methodS defined on the generic function f specialized for a'. It could be more than one.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Ok, I see. It's just that in this particular case I specialized just over one argument, so it looked like "implementing the method". CLOS's way shifts the focus quite a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think, that there is a general solution. Consider: what should happen, for example, if class `A` has some slots, which are not simply initialized from some `:initarg`, but, say, during `initialize-instance` or `shared-initialize`?

That said, as long as you are in control of all involved classes, you could try

- make a protocol implemented by `A`, something along the lines of

  ```
  (defgeneric initargs-for-copy (object)
    (:method-combination append)
    (:method append (object) nil))

  (defmethod initargs-for-copy append ((object a))
    (list :a-1 (slot-value object 'a-1) :a-2 (slot-value object 'a-2)))

  (defun make-b (b-1 a-obj)
    (apply #'make-instance 'b :b-1 b-1 (initargs-for-copy a-obj)))
  ```
- use the MOP to extract the slots at run-time (this may require knowledge about the Lisp implementation of your choice, or the help of some library, like `closer-mop` available via [quicklisp](http://quicklisp.org))

  ```
  (defun list-init-args (object)
    (let* ((class (class-of object))
           (slots (closer-mop:class-slots class)))
      (loop
        for slot in slots
        for name = (closer-mop:slot-definition-name slot)
        for keyword = (closer-mop:slot-definition-initargs slot)
        when (and keyword (slot-boundp object name))
          nconc (list (car keyword) (slot-value object name)))))

  (defun make-b (b-1 a-obj)
     (apply #'make-instance 'b :b-1 b-1 (list-init-args a-obj)))
  ```
- use [`change-class`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/f_chg_cl.htm#change-class) to transmogrify the `A` instance into a `B` instance
  destructively.

Regardless: I am not sure, whether your use-case actually warrants inheritance. The composition approach seems (from a design point of view) much clearer here. Besides having `B` inherit some generic method implementations via `A`: are instances of `B` really considered to be proper instances of `A` in your actual application (i.e., is there an `is-a?` relationship)? Or are you just trying to avoid having to provide the wrappers here?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't think about non-trivial initialization... I am trying to decide the relationships between the building blocks to compose them properly. Thus, I thought of this idea. So far it seems that composition will work better than inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do can be done using composition as a form of prototypal inheritance where an object "inherits" from another instance.

```
(defclass prototype-mixin ()
  ((parent :initarg :parent :initform nil :accessor parent)))

(defmethod slot-unbound (c (p prototype-mixin) slot)
  (declare (ignore c))
  (let ((parent (parent p)))
    (if parent
      (slot-value parent slot)
      (call-next-method))))
```

Now, you define two classes:

```
(defclass a ()
  ((slot :initarg :slot)))

(defclass b (a prototype-mixin) 
  ((other :initarg :other)))
```

When you create a `b` from an existing instance of `a`, you set the `parent` slot of `b` to `a`. Since `b` is also an `a`, there is an unbound  `slot` in `b`. When you try to access this slot, you access the one present in the "parent" object, which is an instance of `a`. But if you want, you can override the value in `b`.

This approach is inspired by [a post](http://www.xach.com/naggum/articles/3196428109878469@naggum.net.html) from Erik Naggum on comp.lang.lisp.